# Reddit feed parser with Google App Script

Tags: parsing, google-apps-script, google-sheets, xml-parsing, reddit

Here my Google script Code.gs:

```
 /* Reddit Scraper written by Amit Agarwal */



var REDDIT = "HomeImprovement";

function run() {

   deleteTriggers_();

  /* Fetch Reddit posts every 5 minutes to avoid hitting
     the reddit and Google Script quotas */
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("scrapReddit")
           .timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();
}


function scrapReddit() {

  // Process 20 Reddit posts in a batch
  var url = "http://www.reddit.com/r/"
            + REDDIT + "/new.xml?limit=100" + getLastID_();

  // Reddit API returns the results in XML format
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var doc = XmlService.parse(response);
  var root = doc.getRootElement();

  var entries = root.getChildren("feed")[0].getChildren("entry");


  var data = new Array();

  for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {

    /* Extract post date, title, description and link from Reddit */

    var date = entries[i].getChild('updated').getText();
    var title = entries[i].getChild('title').getText();
    var desc = entries[i].getChild('content').getText();
    var link = entries[i].getChild('link').getText();

    data[i] = new Array(date, title, desc, link);
  }

  if (data.length == 0) {
    /* There's no data so stop the background trigger */
    deleteTriggers_();
  } else {
    writeData_(data);
  }
}


/* Write the scrapped data in a batch to the
   Google Spreadsheet since this is more efficient */
function writeData_(data) {

  if (data.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var col = sheet.getLastColumn();

  var range = sheet.getRange(row+1, 1, data.length, 4);
  try {
    range.setValues(data);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
}

/* Use the ID of the last processed post from Reddit as token */
function getLastID_() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var col = sheet.getLastColumn();

  var url = sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue().toString();
  var pattern = /.*comments\/([^\/]*).*/;
  var id = url.match(pattern);

  return id ? "&after=t3_" + id[1] : "";

}

/* Posts Extracted, Delete the Triggers */
function deleteTriggers_() {
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i=0; i<triggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }
}
```

This is the error generated when I run the script:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getChildren' of undefined (line 29, file "code")

Here the URL Feed: https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeImprovement/new.xml?limit=100

Any help?

Thanks

more text more text more text more text more text

Comment: 1.Reddit provides json feed too. Why are you parsing xml? 2. Why don't you tell us which line is the 29th line? Do you expect us to count and figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
var entries = root.getChildren("feed")[0].getChildren("entry");
```

throws an error because `<feed>` *is* the root element of the document and does not contain another `<feed>` element inside, so the `root.getChildren("feed")[0]` expression returns `undefined` and then you're running

```
var entries = undefined.getChildren("entry");
```

Furthermore, you need to include the [namespace](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/namespace#getNamespace(String)) in order to get all the `<entry>` elements.

```
var namespace = XmlService.getNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
var entries = root.getChildren("entry", namespace);
```